# How to submit a form via AJAX using a different action?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a form element and that has a normal submit button but I also want to be able to submit an AJAX get request using the values entered in the form but make it to a different address (this is independed of the submit button).

Is there an easy way to do that?

---

The long version: I have a form with several select elements in it and want to repopulate them (updating them to the new set of valid values) each time the user sets one of them.

Comment: So you're asking whether you can have a submit button send the data to both your server and a "different address"?

Comment: @eykanal: No, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easiest if you use a library ([Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries)). With the help of such a library, it becomes almost trivially easy to do this.

[**Prototype**](http://prototypejs.org) example:

```
$('theFormElementId').request({
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        // GET was successful
    }
});
```

that uses Prototype's [`Form#request`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/request/), but you could use [`Ajax.Request`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/request/) instead and get the form data via [`Form#serialize`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/serialize/) (`Form#request` basically just does that for you).

[**jQuery**](http://jquery.com) example:

```
$.get("yoururl", $('#theFormElementId').serialize(), function(data) {
    // The GET was successful
});
```

That uses jQuery's [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) functions (you could use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `$.get` for more control/options).

It's totally possible to do this without a library, it's just a lot more work.