# Using Google's Visualization API and Closure to generate a BarChart

Tags: jquery, visualization, google-closure

I have a web page that uses Google's Visualization API to generate a timeline but now that I'm trying to add some jQuery stuff to it, things are falling over. So, I'm trying to do it with Closure. However I can't seem to find any examples of how to use the Visualization API under Closure. *Does anyone know where I can find any examples?*

What I've got now is based on (read copied wholesale) the [Google Annotated Timeline Example](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) with a little modification to load the data via AJAX as JSON. Right now the AJAX query is to a hard coded URL and I'm trying to make it [construct the URL from a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959185/how-to-submit-a-form-via-ajax-using-a-different-action).

---

I've found how to do time lines:

```
goog.require('gviz.AnnotatedTimeLine');
goog.require('gviz.DataTable');
goog.require('gviz.DataView');

//...

var dataTable = new gviz.DataTable(json_string, 0.6);
var ChartDiv = document.getElementById(chart_id);
chart = new gviz.AnnotatedTimeLine(ChartDiv);
chart.draw(dataTable, {'displayAnnotations': true});
```

Unfortunately, I have yet to find how to make a [Bar/Column Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/columnchart.html) (asking for 'gviz.BarChart' results in compile time errors).

---

What ended up working:

In the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="My.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["columnchart"]})
  var ChartGen = function(x) {
    return new google.visualization.ColumnChart(x);
  }
  drawBar(ChartGen);
</script>
```

In the JS:

```
function drawBar(Lambda) {
  dataTable = new gviz.DataTable(json_string, 0.6);
  var ChartDiv = document.getElementById('chart');
  chart = Lambda(ChartDiv);
  chart.draw(dataTable, {});
}
```

Comment: Give us a sample so we can see what your trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Google Chart Wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_wizard.html) and click on the chart style that you want.

The next page has a button on the right hand side: "Embed with Visualization API". Clicking this will give you the code you need. If you want to customise the chart, you can do that before clicking this button.

Comment: First I'd rather not use image charts and second, "new google.visualization.*" doesn't work under closure.

Comment: As it happens, only one line of what that gives doesn't work so adding a lambda as a level of indirection solves it.

Answer (score 1):

closure-library provides goog.ui.ServerChart.

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_ServerChart.html

See the demo for an example of how to use it:

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/serverchart.html

Comment: That's using the server side rendering. I'm specifically looking for the client side SVG/Canvas rendered form.

Comment: Makes sense. To help anyone else reading this, [goog.ui.ServerChart](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/closure-library-discuss/GslON64NSEA) has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms) so it isn't good for new code.